# Serializer inside Serializer Object C#

Tags: c#

I am not sure exactly what is the source of the error I am having so please request more detail if it will help. For some reason, when I try and deserialize my object not all the data is return(looking at the text file it all looks as if the data is there).

Here is the the things I think can id what the issue is(There is a lot of code on this project so a lot of things have been cut out to make it easier to read) :

```
[Serializable]
public class Unit
{
    public List<ModuleSlot> slotsInFront { get; set; }

    //this would never be reached because the module slot has a customer xml serial object that prevents the normal xml reader from reaching this
    public string some_fake_text{get;set;}
 }

public class ModuleSlot
{
    [XmlIgnore()]
    public StreamShape moduleShape { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("moduleShape")]
    public ShapeSerializer xmlModuleShape
    {
        get
        {
            if (moduleShape == null)
                return null;
            else
            {
                return new ShapeSerializer(moduleShape);
            }
        }
        set
        {
            moduleShape = value.getFirstShape();
        }
    }

}
public class ShapeSerializer : IXmlSerializable
{

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
        System.Xml.XmlReader subReader = XmlReader.Create(reader.ReadSubtree(), settings);
        subReader.ReadStartElement();
        while (subReader.Depth > 0)
        {
            xmlStreamShape newXmlShape = new xmlStreamShape();
            newXmlShape = (xmlStreamShape)new XmlSerializer(typeof(xmlStreamShape)).Deserialize(subReader);
            parameters.Add(newXmlShape.getShapeFromSaved());
            subReader.Read();
        }
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");
        foreach (StreamShape item in parameters)
        {
            xmlStreamShape convertedShape = new xmlStreamShape(item);
            new XmlSerializer(typeof(xmlStreamShape)).Serialize(writer, convertedShape, ns);
        }
    }
}
```

...

Comment: It's too difficult to read that much code on StackOverflow. Try to narrow it down more.

Comment: Cut down some...<shape4Port><xmlStreamShape>...</xmlStreamShape></shape4Port> I think the issue is due to the two items, but I am not sure...

Comment: Also the above code dose not throw any exceptions...

Comment: What data in particular is not being returned? I would start testing the success of your serialization/deserialization technique from bottom up.  That is, try successfully serializing and deserializing an instance of ShapeSerializer first, then do it for ModuleSlot, then do it for Unit.

Comment: The serialization works on one item at a time, but what I see is that whenever I get to one of the custom objects that implements IXmlSerializable, no other following properties get serialization. This is what I was trying to say above that makes me think the issue is due to  my ReadXml method. Not sure why though...my guess is that once the custom interface starts it causes the parent reader to ignores all the other properties... the only work around I have found is to do the custom interfaces last...but that dosnt work for classes that need 2 custom xml readers(i.e when the unit using slot)

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue in the xml writer. I moved away from a serialization on the shape so wont post an example of that on here but here is a method that had the same issue but has been resolved(feel free to post any issues you see with it):

```
public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
{
        //Skip whitespaces
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
        //Create a reader that will read the list's content
        System.Xml.XmlReader subReader = XmlReader.Create(reader.ReadSubtree(), settings);
        subReader.MoveToContent();
        subReader.ReadStartElement();
        while (subReader.Depth > 0)
        {
            Type type = Type.GetType(this.GetType().Namespace + "." + reader.Name);
            parameters.Add((Port)new XmlSerializer(type).Deserialize(subReader));
        }
        reader.ReadEndElement();
}
```